# Loss of precision while converting floats to strings in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, floating-point

I am converting in Python some floats (some shorter some longer) to strings and getting unexpected (?) results:

**Case 1**

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format
pd.DataFrame({'x': [12345.67]})

           x
0   12345.67
```

**Case 2**

```
pd.DataFrame({'x': [1234589890808980.67]})

                      x
0   1234589890808980.75
```

**Case 3**

```
pd.DataFrame({'x': [1234589890878708980.67]})

                         x
0   1234589890878708992.00
```

I even tried dtypes `np.float128` and `np.longdouble`, but without avail.

Can somebody please explain what is happenning here and is "proper" conversion posiible in Cases 2 and 3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this "issue" happens in the Python (instead of pandas) side. When you have some instant values like `1234589890878708980.67` it's recognized as `float` and loses precision instantly, e.g.:

```
>>> 1234589890878708980.67
1.234589890878709e+18
>>> 1234589890878708980.67 == 1234589890878708980.6712345
True
```

You might try something like `decimal.Decimal`:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> pd.DataFrame({'x': [decimal.Decimal('1234589890808980.67')]})
                     x
0  1234589890808980.67
```

**EDITED:**

OP's added a few questions in the comment.

> However, do I understand it right that for this method work correctly the value should be string in the first place?

Yes :)

> What if it's float read from csv file?

AFAIK Python's `csv` reader shall not have performed any type conversion, and you'll get strings that could be later converted freely. Otherwise if you're using `pandas.read_csv`, you could try setting the `dtype` and `float_precision` arguments (you could also ask pandas to load plain strings, and have the values converted later yourself).

Comment: This worked indeed! However, do I understand it right that for this method work correctly the value should be string in the first place? What if it's float read from `csv` file?

Comment: Thanks, absolutely agree with your suggestions (even tried some already). Is there a way to increase precision via `np.float128` or `np.longdouble` as to your knowledge? My attempts failed for some reason....